# Can't resolve module JHipster Micro-frontend

Tags: angular, jhipster, micro-frontend, jhipster-gateway

Hi I am running the command to generate microfrontend applications/microservices.  I am running into the following errors when deploying my gateway application:

```
[INFO] ./src/main/webapp/app/app-routing.module.ts:28:36-76 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'geonamesservice/entity-routing' in '/Users/amar/workspace/saathratri-app-holder/saathratrigateway/src/main/webapp/app'
[INFO] 
[INFO] ./src/main/webapp/app/app-routing.module.ts:32:36-75 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tajvoteservice/entity-routing' in '/Users/amar/workspace/saathratri-app-holder/saathratrigateway/src/main/webapp/app'
[INFO] 
[INFO] ./src/main/webapp/app/app-routing.module.ts:36:36-81 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'organizationsservice/entity-routing' in '/Users/amar/workspace/saathratri-app-holder/saathratrigateway/src/main/webapp/app'
[INFO] 
[INFO] ./src/main/webapp/app/app-routing.module.ts:40:36-89 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'saathratrimaintenanceservice/entity-routing' in '/Users/amar/workspace/saathratri-app-holder/saathratrigateway/src/main/webapp/app'
[INFO] 
[INFO] ./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.component.ts:585:6-51 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'geonamesservice/entity-navbar-items' in '/Users/amar/workspace/saathratri-app-holder/saathratrigateway/src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar'
[INFO] 
[INFO] ./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.component.ts:592:20-64 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'geonamesservice/translation-module' in '/Users/amar/workspace/saathratri-app-holder/saathratrigateway/src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar'
[INFO] 
[INFO] ./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.component.ts:604:6-50 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tajvoteservice/entity-navbar-items' in '/Users/amar/workspace/saathratri-app-holder/saathratrigateway/src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar'
[INFO] 
[INFO] ./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.component.ts:611:20-63 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tajvoteservice/translation-module' in '/Users/amar/workspace/saathratri-app-holder/saathratrigateway/src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar'
[INFO] 
[INFO] ./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.component.ts:623:6-56 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'organizationsservice/entity-navbar-items' in '/Users/amar/workspace/saathratri-app-holder/saathratrigateway/src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar'
[INFO] 
[INFO] ./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.component.ts:630:20-69 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'organizationsservice/translation-module' in '/Users/amar/workspace/saathratri-app-holder/saathratrigateway/src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar'
[INFO] 
[INFO] ./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.component.ts:642:6-64 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'saathratrimaintenanceservice/entity-navbar-items' in '/Users/amar/workspace/saathratri-app-holder/saathratrigateway/src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar'
[INFO] 
[INFO] ./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.component.ts:649:20-77 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'saathratrimaintenanceservice/translation-module' in '/Users/amar/workspace/saathratri-app-holder/saathratrigateway/src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar'
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed the following in webpack.custom.js:

```
 config = merge(
    config,
    require('./webpack.microfrontend')(config, options, targetOptions)
    // jhipster-needle-add-webpack-config - JHipster will add custom config
  );
```

Now I no longer get the module not found errors.